# SWF SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context

Tags: security, flash

Hi
I have a flash image gallery that  worked just fine, until few days a go it stopped loading the images. the debugger  throws this error :

```
SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.
```

can someone explain what can be the cause?

Comment: Are you loading images from the same domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did your images extensions change, possibly from like .jpg to .JPG or something?

Typically this is called if there is a problem with your external media.  Here's a workaround for it, but I typically try and solve versus make it go away.

```
setTimeout( function():void{fileReference.load();}, 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. first of all thanks. the point is that when i am loading the swf localy. i get the images from the server without any problem. its happening only in the site. second thing is that i have similar gallery in other oage in the site and it works fine.

Comment: Like gAMBOOK asked, are you loading the images from the same domain?

Comment: Ok. it was an other problem. now the images are loading but i still got that error, and your code fixed that. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this problem when working with loading images where the path is located in an external XML file.  So... I load the XML get the path from it but then the problem I had was I was loading  30+ images and the error was popping up only 6 times so.. I had no idea which file locations where the bad ones.

If you want flash to out put more info than just :

```
SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.
```

Add this event listener to your Loader:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

and finally this function:

```
protected function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
    trace(e.text);
}
```

With this in place your Security Error will convert to a **URL Not Found** Error with the file location you supplied.  With this information in hand it should be easier for you to debug the problem.

```
Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: file:////Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/cleanshooter/Documents/Website%20/here/there/everywhere/30805/filename.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue before,the final conclusion was related to **incorrect image path or name**

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this issue and used the above setTimeout example but for a slightly different purpose. I was calling a php script that hit Twitter and got the same security issue in Flash debug player. I just wanted to add my example which builds on the above to show how you can use this "workaround" for URLLoader as well as fileReference.

```
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 

var urlStr:String = "http://www.yourdomain.com/php/twitter.php"; 
var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
myVariables.twitterID = "yourtwitterID";

var myURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlStr)
myURLRequest.data = myVariables;

setTimeout(function():void {  myXMLLoader.load( myURLRequest ); }, 1);

myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoadHandler);
```

Comment: Is this AS2? I can't find the setTimeout function in AS3. Do you know how this could be done in 3?

Answer (score 1):

In response to headwinds:

---

In AS3 you need to import flash.utils.setTimeout. The syntax for setTimeout is `setTimeout(A, B, ...rest);`

Where B is the function to get called afterwards,
A is the delay in ms (e.g. 1000 for a second)
and C is any number of parameters you need to provide for the function, separated by a comma.

E.g.

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
// package, etc
//main function
setTimeout(respond, 500, true, false);
private function respond(A : Boolean, B : Boolean) : void {
   var result : Boolean = A == B;
   trace(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the error:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onHTTPError);
protected function onHTTPError(e:HTTPStatusEvent):void{
     trace("HTTPError"+e.status);
}
```

This way it will handle the error and works fine.