# Debugging Flash through via browser - Security Context Error

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying to use a browser to debug my flash app as it needs External Interface. But whenever I try to attach the Flex Debugger to the browser running Flash app, it shows

```
SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.
```

I already checked [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065768/swf-securityerror-error-2000-no-active-security-context) with same title as my error but changing code is not the solution here as it is an existing code and I don't get this error while using a debug version or when I am not running connected to a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the above solution, also check that the Flash Builder feature of Network Monitor is turned OFF, before you compile and run the app.

Comment: By "above solution" i meant The_asMan's solution on crossdomain.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are embedding correctly

```
allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
allownetworking = "all";
```

If that is set then make sure your crossdomain.xml is set up properly.