# Flash Error: SecurityError #2000

Tags: flash, security, actionscript, image

I have a Flash-file, which I downloaded at a page. Now I am changing some things and this error is occuring: SecurityError #2000.

The Flash-file loads an XML-file and in this XML-file, there are some paths to some picture files. All paths are valid and the pictures exists. When I changed the picture (and path), I get this SecurityError.

My next idea was to replace the picture, but the path should be the original. When I did this, i got the old picture, not the new.

I downloaded this Flash-file: http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_252_bubble

Answer (score 0):

1. Go here: [Global Security Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).
2. Add the location containing your files to the settings panel and click Always Allow. It should end up looking something like this:

[image]

Then try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that solution didn't helped. I even tested it with uploading all files to a server and visiting my site.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "SecurityError #2000" happens when you're loading external assets and the file names are the wrong case (uppercase vs. lowercase), at least according to this:

http://blog.vandenoostende.com/2009/securityerror-error-2000-no-active-security-context/

Try to verify that you've got the file names right.

Comment: I looked at the filenames and even if all characters are written like the explorer (uppercase and lowercase) and they are all the same. But that didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a few things, however I'm unable to reproduce this issue on my machine. Any more details about it are welcome. You should check this thread:
[SWF SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065768/swf-securityerror-error-2000-no-active-security-context)
and this post:
http://www.actionscripterrors.com/?p=409